# Is Dal Dal cat ears is just hair accessory?

Tags: girls-of-the-wilds

Is there a reason that no one notice Dal Dal cat ears?
I'm not very familiar with the Korean traditions, but I don't think it's just a hair accessory because sometimes when she get excited she reveal a cat tail.
And I also remember there were some guy who cheer for Moon-Young who has a bear ears, so she couldn't be the only one (isn't?).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from the wiki of this [manga](http://girlsofthewilds.wikia.com/) :

[image]

> [Dal Dal](http://girlsofthewilds.wikia.com/wiki/Dal_Dal_Choi) always sports a pair of tiger ears. The tiger ears are
>   actually detachable and are pinned to her hair. The author also
>   sometimes adds a tail on her.